# como hacer para que mi botón escuche el evento que estoy pasando

Tags: javascript, jquery

el problema es que mi boton no escucha a la funcion que le paso,la idea es que cuando aplaste el boton en el DOM me salgue que hice click e imprima un innerhtml en la pagina web. agradezco su ayuda

```
$(function() {
  'use strict';


var calculo =$('medidas_preventivas');

if ($('calculo')) {
/*if contenedor*/
/*event listener*/
calculo.addEventListener('click' , calcularF);

function calcularF(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("has echo click en calcular");
/*nuenas variables*/
var tiempoCarga = parseInt(tiempoCarga.value);
var pesoCarga = parseInt(pesoCarga.value);

  if (tiempoCarga > 8 && pesoCarga > 25) {
resultado.innerHtml= " texto ";

}else {
  resultado.innerHtml="texto";
}

}

}

});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usar jquery o javascript, una de dos.

```
var calculo =$('medidas_preventivas').click(...);
```

o ->

```
document.getElementById('medidas_preventivas').addEventListener("click", calcularF);
```

Comment: muchas gracias ya lo logre:)

Answer (score 2):

Te comento que veo que usas JQuery entonces en vez de usar innerHTML solo debes usar html() que es el método propio de JQuery; además te dejo un ejemplo funcional para que veas su comportamiento y lu puedas adaptar a tus necesidades

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="toca">Tocame</button>
  <div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
      $("#toca").click(function(){
        $("#app").html("diste click")
      })
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Como observas para hacer que el botón escuche el evento, le doy acceso
>   al evento click; pero para eso primero acceso a dicho botón por su id
>   con esto #id